# Using a DLL (Dynamic Link Library) written in Visual Basic with the ActiveX technology

Tags: vb.net, flutter, dart, dll, dllimport

Is there any way to import a DLL file which has been created in .Net platform ( Visual Basic) in **Flutter**?